# jQuery multiple handler registration issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page which adds row by row on each click.
I use this code:

```
$('#addCnt').live('click', function () { .. };
```

Problem is when I reload the part of the page together with that code, it registers the handler again, so when button is clicked after that it appends N number of rows, where N = number of total page reload.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Can you show your markup se we can see where is this button. Is there a button by row ?

Comment: How are you reloading a part of the page?

Comment: @dakt: So what are you doing, calling `live()` again? Adding the same elements again?

Comment: Yes, Ajax reloads markup and JS which holds .live(). So on every reload handler is registered.

Comment: @dakt: Ah. Don't load JavaScript with Ajax then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a given page, you need to make sure that your code to attach the event handler is never run more than once.  So this code:

```
$('#addCnt').live('click', function () { .. };
```

should not be run multiple times.

If you can't restructure your code to prevent this from being run more than once, then you can create your own global flag to protect it:

```
if (typeof window.addCntProtection == "undefined")  {
    window.addCntProtection = false;
}
if (!window.addCntProtection) {
    $('#addCnt').live('click', function () { .. };
    window.addCntProtection = true;
}
```

Incidentally, jQuery has deprecated the use of `.live()` and it is no longer recommended for any version of jQuery.  They recommend you use `.on()` for jQuery 1.7+ or `.delegate()` for earlier versions of jQuery.

Comment: OK, thanks...I will try your approach since code restructuring is out of the question.

Comment: @dakt - after the appropriate amount of time has passed, you can select the answer you think is the best answer by clicking the checkmark under the arrows.  That will also give you some more repuatation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `live` on a selector, you have to attach it only once and it will work on any number of elements on the page.

Move your code to attach `live` handler outside of the code to reload part of page, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, [the `.live()` method is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Remove the event handlers before refreshing the page with `.off()`.
Example:

```
$('#addCnt').on('click',function(){
    alert('Clicked.');
});

$('#a').on('click',function(){
    $('#addCnt').on('click',function(){
        alert('Clicked.');
    });
});

$('#r').on('click',function(){
    $('#addCnt').off('click');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WccQy/

You can add as many handlers as you want. `.off()` removes **all** of them. Take a look at the jsfiddle!